# Audio recording does not play in safari when recorded form the chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, audio, safari

the problem is when i recorded the audio form the safari and it plays fine in the safari and when record the audio in chrome it plays fine in chrome
but when i record the audio in the chrome and play in safari it plays it whole and once the progress bar play whole audio at once but does not heare any sound.
and when i record the audio in safari it plays fine in the chrome

i  am using react-media-recorder-2 to record

here is the code for recorder

```
sexport const AudioBarPlayer = forwardRef<IAudioBarRef, AudioBarProps>((props: AudioBarProps, ref) =>
{
  const src = props.src;
  const scrollable = props.scrollable;
  const onChangeDuration = props.onChangeDuration;
  const onStopPlaying = props.onStopPlaying;
  const onStartPlaying = props.onStartPlaying;
  const cursorColor = props.cursorColor;
  const progressColor = props.progressColor;
  const waveColor = props.waveColor;
  const audioElementRef = useRef(new Audio());
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const waveSurferRef = useRef<WaveSurfer>();
  audioElementRef.current.controls = true;

  useEffect(() =>
  {
    waveSurferRef.current = WaveSurfer.create({
      cursorColor: cursorColor,
      progressColor: progressColor,
      // @ts-ignore
      container: containerRef.current,
      barWidth: 2,
      barRadius: 1,
      barGap: 3,
      waveColor: waveColor,
      cursorWidth: 2,
      height: 30,
      barHeight: scrollable ? 3 : 1,
      hideScrollbar: true,
      media: audioElementRef.current,
      duration: props.durationMs && (props.durationMs / 1000)
    });

    return () =>
    {
      waveSurferRef.current?.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() =>
  {
    if(src)
    {
      waveSurferRef.current?.load(src).then(() =>
      {
        if(waveSurferRef.current)
        {
          onChangeDuration(props.durationMs
            ? (props.durationMs / 1000)
            : parseInt(waveSurferRef.current.getDuration().toString()));
        }
        waveSurferRef.current?.on("seeking", (args) =>
        {
          onChangeDuration(parseInt(args.toString()));
        });
        waveSurferRef.current?.on("finish", () =>
        {
          waveSurferRef.current?.seekTo(0);
          onStopPlaying();
          onChangeDuration(undefined);
        });
        waveSurferRef.current?.on("audioprocess", (args) =>
        {
          onChangeDuration(parseInt(args.toString()));
        });
        waveSurferRef.current?.on("play", () => onStartPlaying(waveSurferRef.current?.getCurrentTime() || 0));
        waveSurferRef.current?.on("pause", onStopPlaying);
        waveSurferRef.current?.on("destroy", onStopPlaying);
      });
    }
  }, [src]);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () =>
  {
    return {
      play: () => waveSurferRef.current?.play().catch(() =>
      {
        if(src)
        {
          axios.get(src, {
              responseType: "blob"
            }
          ).then((response) =>
          {
            const blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "audio/mp3; codecs=opus"});
            console.log("===response.data", response.data);
            waveSurferRef.current?.loadBlob(blob).then(() => waveSurferRef.current?.play());
          });
        }
      }),
      pause: () => waveSurferRef.current?.pause()
    };
  }, [waveSurferRef.current]);

  return (
    <div
      id="AudioBar"
      style={{
        width: "100%"
      }}
      ref={containerRef}
    />
  );
});
```

i want that when i record it in chrome it should also play in safari`

Comment: `audio/mp3; codecs=opus` is that like putting diesel in your tesla?

Comment: so any suggestion what should i do( i remove that still does not work)

Comment: I also have found to set the content header type to audio/mpeg but as when i send the audio form safari it plays fine so i think that is not the issue. if you have any other issue then please help